# How to properly pass arguments from a bottle view to a decorated view?

Tags: python, decorator, bottle

I would like to protect my view with a CSRF token, and the approach I took for the is the following:

```
from functools import partial
from bottle import jinja2_template as template,

def generate_csrf_token(length):
    '''Generate a random string using range [a-zA-Z0-9].'''
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join([choice(chars) for i in range(length)])


def require_csrf(callback, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.params.csrf_token
        if not token or token != global_vars['csrf_token']:
            abort(400)
        body = callback(*args, **kwargs)
        return body

    return wrapper

global_vars = {'BCC_VERSION': pkg_resources.get_distribution('bcc').version,
               'csrf_token': generate_csrf_token(48)}

j2template = partial(template, template_settings={'globals': global_vars})

@app.get("/remove/")
@require_csrf
def remove_device():
    ans = {'status': 200,
           'body': "csrf_token is: {}".format(global_vars['csrf_token'])}
    return HTTPResponse(**ans)
```

This works fine as long as the view does not expect any parameters. If the view accepts a database connection (when using a plugin for example) things get tricky:

```
@app.get("/delete/")
@require_csrf
def delete_device(db):  # This causes the require_csrf decorator to fail
    ans = {'status': 200,
           'body': "csrf_token is: {}".format(global_vars['csrf_token'])}
    return HTTPResponse(**ans)
```

When accessing `/delete/` I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/bcc/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 979, in _handle
    out = route.call(**args)
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/bcc/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1949, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/home/oznt/Software/bcc/bcc/views.py", line 32, in wrapper
    body = callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: delete_device() missing 1 required positional argument: 'db'
```

To get around this, I modified the `require_csrf` decorator slightly to be:

```
def require_csrf(callback, *args, **kwargs):
    import inspect
    callback_args = inspect.getargspec(callback)[0]

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.params.csrf_token
        if not token or token != global_vars['csrf_token']:
            abort(400)
        body = callback(*callback_args, **kwargs)
        return body

    return wrapper
```

And now things work as expected. However, I am not sure this is the correct way to solve this problem. Can you comment on this or suggest a better solution for that problem?

#### update

I tried the suggestion of doomsday, and I am getting the following error:

```
python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from bcc.views import app as home_app
  File "/home/oznt/Software/controller_configuration/bcc/views.py", line 66, in <module>
    @require_csrf()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a level of function wrapper here. The code below is working without any `inspect` hack.

```
def require_csrf():
    def decorator(callback):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            token = request.params.csrf_token
            if not token or token != global_vars['csrf_token']:
                abort(400)
            return callback(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@app.get("/remove/<id>")
@require_csrf()
def remove_device(id):
    ans = {'status': 200,
           'body': "csrf_token is: {}".format(global_vars['csrf_token'])}
    return HTTPResponse(**ans)
```

Note also, if needed, you can add arguments to both `require_csrf` decorator and function.

Comment: This approach seems interesting, but this requires modifying all existing views to return the decorator. Also after returning `HTTPResponse`, `decorator` isn't defined, at least that is what the static analysis complains about ...

Comment: @Oz123: it was a typo, I moved `return decorator` in the decorator above :-)

Comment: I finally got to test this! It works as expected, this is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

Does simple `def delete_device():` work?  (I'm not sure why you put the `db` parameter there in the first place, since you don't seem to be using it.)

---

EDIT: What about `def require_csrf(callback):`?  (I removed `*args` or `**kwargs` there, since you don't need them.)

Comment: Ah, I see. You should not need to use `inspect` here.  I've added another suggestion to my answer, give that a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not work... It raises the same error I posted above.